# How to take in keyboard input during a while True loop in Python that leads to an action with the loop still running?

Tags: python

I am working on a mini game, please bear with my code I just started python, and I am at the point where if a certain image is on the screen (Korean symbols) and the user presses that key on an American keyboard that corresponds, then the image will disappear and create a new one that comes down the screen. How would I go about registering the key marks and making sure they correspond to the correct image in the simplest fashion?

This is placed in a class:

```
korean_characters = [a, e, i, o, u, eo, eu, ae,
                             ya, ye, yo, yu, yeo, yae,
                             g, kk, n, d, tt, l, m, b, pp, s, ss, ng, j, jj, ch, k, t, p, h]
```

And each letter corresponds to a matrix like so:

```
a = [[1, 0],
     [1, 0],
     [1, 1],
     [1, 0],
     [1, 0]
     ]
```

These are then drawn onto a large grid that takes up the window. They move and are registered according to this loop:

```
while True:
    wn.update()
    end_game = False

    for i in symbol_list:
        if i.y == 48 - i.height + 1:
            i.erase_symbol(grid)
            symbol_list.remove(i)
            end_game = True

        elif i.can_move(grid) and i.check_grid(grid):
            # Erase current shape
            i.erase_symbol(grid)
            i.y += 1

            i.draw_symbol(grid)

        else:
            i.erase_symbol(grid)
            symbol_list.remove(i)
            symbol_list.append(Korean())


    draw_grid(pen, grid)
    draw_redline()

    time.sleep(delay)

    if end_game:
        break

print("GAME OVER")
```

The symbol list simply is a list with anywhere from 3 to 9 of the class objects (matrices)

So with the examples I gave, the 'a' matrix when on screen corresponds to 'k' on an American keyboard. How do I make it so that when k is pressed, it is registered and can be compared to the list of korean_characters. It should be able to take in any key press and even combos like 'shift + e'. If I can get help on this part I know how to make them disappear.

Comment: It seems as though you do not want the program to be interrupted like a input() statement would do. Have you looked into libraries such as pynput?

Comment: I looked into pynput and keyboard, however it just seems as though the methods dont fully achieve what I like, although I may be using them incorrectly. If someone knows how my question could be accomplished with one of those, then that would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

After some trials and tribulation, I actually found a solution using the turtle onkeypress() alongside some self-defined functions.

For each symbol there is a function related to it as so:

```
def check_a():
    for c in symbol_list:
        if c.symbol_name == dict_symbol_index['k']:
            c.erase_symbol(grid)
            symbol_list.remove(c)
            symbol_list.append(Korean())
```

And then using the turtle module and the function, it is compared to its respective key:

```
wn.onkeypress(check_a, 'k')
...
wn.listen()
```